# I need insert automatic in relational table in access

Tags: ms-access

How I can automatically fill the relational table writing in Table 1 and 2 without typing anything in TableRelation in access?

I have many content in Table1 and Table2 and I want to copy the primary keys in the tableRelation

These are the images of relations in my access

```
https://mega.co.nz/#!v8B0WSYY!w-xKYcyWV_zH0XRUwn_FNqJkpYa02CQTu_LeP_L2e5U
https://mega.co.nz/#!CwphlbyQ!pdVG9XuHvSq9_R1dmNbD4n0xiO8IgODAVSCiwxWIVeU
https://mega.co.nz/#!2gxRBBqY!OERBDdr2BKqzfXRTmomD_Ao4E7j2xj2E4bjOhWn7SFE
https://mega.co.nz/#!b1xikDSL!x5l-ReZJbJgsQPzO794--uEBB8tNOFDfpnYrglDbmkI
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an append query that takes recs from Table1 and Table2 to make recs in tableRelation.